# How to hide a paragraph using v-if through vuex?

Tags: vue.js, vuex, nuxt.js

I am trying to create a small app in which i can click on the button and hide the paragraph but i am trying to implement that using vuex.I have a paragraph in my Home.vue file and a button in my About.vue File. I want the paragraph hide conditionally in the click of the button but i want to accomplish that using vuex. How would i do that? My store.js, home.vue and About.vue are as follows.

```
This is how my store looks like.
import Vue from 'vue'
import Vuex from 'vuex'

Vue.use(Vuex)

export default new Vuex.Store({
  state: {
    show:true,
  },
  mutations: {
   toggle : state => {
     state.show = !state.show
   }
  },
  actions: {

  }
})

This is the Home.vue file
<template>
<p>This needs to disappear</p>
</template>

<script>
import {mapMutations} from "vuex"

export default {
 computed : {
   ...mapMutations ([
     "toggle"
   ])
 }
}
</script>

This is the About.vue file
<template>
  <div>
    <button @click="toggle">Click Me</button>
  </div>
</template>


<script>
import {mapMutations} from "vuex"

export default {
 computed : {
   ...mapMutations ([
     "toggle"
   ])
 }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

the `mapMutations` should be used in methods not in computed property :

```
 methods:{
          ...mapMutations ([
             "toggle"
           ])
  }
```

like you see in the [`official docs`](https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/mutations.html#committing-mutations-in-components) :

> You can commit mutations in components with this.$store.commit('xxx'), or use the mapMutations helper which maps component methods to store.commit calls (requires root store injection):

Comment: oh yeah i see(my bad). But then how do i condition that state on the paragraph so when i click on the button, the paragraph should hide?

Comment: you could do `<p v-if="$store.state.show">This needs to disappear</p>` or use mapGetters in your computed property

Comment: wow,thanks it worked but could you explain how directly accessing $store in the template works? does vuex injects that automatically in each component?

Comment: because you're injecting the store in the vue instance like `new Vue({el:"#app",store,data(){...},....})`

Comment: okay i see. Thank you so much. You always seem to help me out.Appreciate it brother

Comment: I have updated the above code, what i'm doing right now is that i am looping through an array of special types and all the list have their own page which share the same paragraph as shown above. How can i maintain it such that when i hide the paragraph, it is hidden only on apple page and not from the rest of the pages? I have also added my app.vue file so that you can what's going on.

Comment: please post a new question and keep this like it was before in order to be organized, ok?

Comment: Done:  here is the link :-   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54313902/hiding-a-pargraph-using-v-if-through-vuex-but-containing-that-in-a-specific-tab